# Create Product on Wix Store via Rest API

Tags: rest, api

I have a Wix Store Website and want to operate over the store via a REST API. Does Wix Provides API for Creating/Updating/Fetching products, orders etc?

I have checked the [Http_API](https://dev.wix.com/docs/http-api/using-http-api/) but didn't find any information regarding product creation. Please guide if there are any Endpoints for the same.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Yes i'm looking for the same thing

Comment: @Nidel Fds : After putting in a lot of time I am not able to find the endpoints for Wix Store.

Comment: I guess they don't have one, you need to custom build it

Comment: Today is May 19, 2019 and I'm still looking for the same thing. But I think you can use Wix Admin API for fetching products.